# batch scripting with date function

Tags: batch-file

have a task assigned to me that I know how to do it other languages, but the Windows batch/cmd requirement has me a little baffled.

I had an requirement like I should write to batch script to copy the set of excel files from `c:` drive to `e:` drive and in `d:` drive i should place only the 7 days files based on the file name with date .

```
a_20120101.xls
a_20120102.xls
b_20120103.xls
```

in `d:` drive there should be only last 7 days files .
when ever 8th day files comes then day1 files should be deleted by right there should be only 7 days files.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this about 15 years ago for just such a purpose:

```
@echo off

if %1!==! (
  echo Deletes all files except newest 7
  echo   Syntax: %0 ^<directory^>
  exit/b
)

if not exist %1 echo Directory %1 does not exist! & exit /b 1
pushd %1

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('dir/o-d/b/a-d ^|findstr /n .') do (
  if %%a GTR 7 "del %%b"
)

popd
```

Run with care though!